# Clear background color on UIBezierPath and fill

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I want to have a view that at the bottom has a curve.

I created this `ArchView` that does the job perfectly except for one thing, the part that is blue I want it to be transparent.

[image]

If I set the background color as `.clear` this is what happens:

[image]

This is the code for the `ArchView`:

```
class ArchedView: UIView {
    let archHeight: CGFloat
    let bColor: UIColor
    let archColor: UIColor
    let contentView: UIView = UIView()

    init(archHeight: CGFloat, bColor: UIColor, archColor: UIColor) {
        self.archHeight = archHeight
        self.bColor = bColor
        self.archColor = archColor
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        backgroundColor = .clear
        addSubview(contentView)

        contentView.backgroundColor = bColor
        contentView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-archHeight)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let height: CGFloat = archHeight
        let ovalRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: height)
        let ovalPath = UIBezierPath()
        ovalPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: (ovalRect.width / 2) * 1.3, startAngle: 180 * .pi/180, endAngle: 0 * .pi/180, clockwise: false)
        ovalPath.addLine(to: CGPoint.zero)

        ovalPath.close()

        var ovalTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: ovalRect.midX, y: frame.height - height)
        ovalTransform = ovalTransform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: height / ovalPath.bounds.height)
        ovalPath.apply(ovalTransform)

        archColor.setFill()
        ovalPath.fill()
    }
}
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the `fill()` but I can't understand what's happening here.

Comment: Check your View.background color

Comment: @ReinierMelian I am not sure I follow you, which view.background color? This is a UIView, not a UIViewController.

Comment: your background color is clear,  `backgroundColor = .clear`

Comment: Why not using mask layer instead?